# Importing New Subscribers to a MailChimp list

Tags: mailchimp

I have an xlsx file with 40,000 emails in column A that I want to import into a new Mailchimp list.  In Mailchimp I've checked "Copy and past contacts from .xls or .xlsx file.  Then I copied the A column to the clipboard in xlxs and pasted it to the "Paste subscriber" box in MailChimp.  The data goes in but when I click Next I get the error "You must have an email address column to import a list."

So I inserted a row at the top of column A in xlsx and wrote "Email Address" there.  Copied again to clipboard and pasted into MailChimp.  Get same error as above.

Tried next copying the A column and pasting into Notepad++. Wrote "Email Address" above the first email, and copied from Notepad++ copied to clipboard.  Selected "Import contacts from .csv or .txt file" in Mailchimp and pasted again.  Still get the same error: "You must have an email address column to import a list."

So what is MailChimp looking for?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you followed all of the steps on [this](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/growth/import-subscribers-to-a-list) help document? It describes how to assign an email column.

Comment: Yes.  The problem was some mal-formed email addresses in the list. MailChimp found it. And it had nothing to do with the "You must have an email address column to import a list" error that MailChimp was throwing.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add all the answers.
It could be because when you export or import your CSV file into the excel it separates the value with a semicolon ";" while MailChimp requires comma ",". In my case, changing the semicolon to use comma fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Beware the line ending, the sample Mailchimp provides have [Linux line ending that are not compatible with Windows line ending](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html)

Hence on Windows it looks like there is no line ending. Hopefully Mailchimp list also works with Windows line ending.

[image]